# graph api Access denied

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I use delegation permission to obtain access token authorization. The user is a global administrator

The scope of authority is offline_ access User.ReadWrite.All Files.ReadWrite.All

I request the API to get the Same tenant subuser drive file

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxx/drive/root/children

Return to access denied

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children  Return is normal

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is expected.

Please see the [delegated permission `Files.ReadWrite.All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#delegated-permissions-23).

[image]

It allows the app to access all files the signed-user **CAN** access. This means that unless that user shares the file with you, you will not have permission to access it.

Let's focus on the [application permission `Files.ReadWrite.All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-22).

[image]

This permission allows the app to access all files.

This difference is what makes you confusing.

So with delegated permission (user token), in addition to `Files.ReadWrite.All`, you still need to let others share the file with you before you can access it.